# Why are function pointers not considered object oriented?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, language-agnostic

In the C# language specifications it explicitly states:

> Delegates are similar to the concept
>   of function pointers found in some
>   other languages, but **unlike function
>   pointers**, delegates are
>   object-oriented and type-safe.

I understand delegates need to be a little more flexible than pointers because .NET moves memory around.  That's the only difference I'm aware of, but I am not sure how this would turn a delegate into in OO concept...?

What makes a function pointer not object oriented?  Are pointers and function pointers equivalent?

Comment: Just a though: type-safety might be the important point here. You can hardly do the same "dirty tricks" with delegates that you can do with "raw" pointers, no matter if they're function pointers or pointers to data.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, Wikipedia says that "object oriented" means using "features such as data abstraction, encapsulation, messaging, modularity, polymorphism, and inheritance." Lacking a better definition, let's go with that.

Function pointers don't contain data, they don't encapsulate implementation details, they neither send nor receive messages, they are not modular, they are not typically used in a polymorphic manner (though I suppose they could in theory be covariant and contravariant in their return and formal parameter types, as delegates now are in C# 4) and they do not participate in an inheritance hierarchy.  They are not self-describing; you can't ask a function pointer for its type because it doesn't have one.

By contrast, delegates capture data -- they hold on to the receiver. They support messaging in the sense that you can "message" a delegate by calling its ToString or GetType or Invoke or BeginInvoke methods to tell it to do something, and it "messages" you back with the result. Delegate types can be restricted to certain accessibility domains if you choose to do so. They are self-describing objects that have metadata and at runtime know their own type. They can be combined with other delegates. They can be used polymorphically as System.MulticastDelegate or System.Delegate, the types from which they inherit. And they can be used polymorphically in the sense that in C# 4 delegate types may be covariant and contravariant in their return and parameter types.

Comment: In C++, functions do some of those OO things, although I agree not enough to qualify as an OO feature. For example they *do* abstract data, in that you can have `static` local variables, but delegates store data in a much better way because you can instantiate the "same" delegate many times at runtime, and get different copies of its data. C++ function pointers do have a type but they don't have a means of querying their dynamic type. In the sense of "message" meaning "method call", they do accept one message - `operator()`. And so on.

Comment: "and it "messages" you back with the result" Don't function pointers do this aswell?

Comment: *"you can't ask a function pointer for its type because it doesn't have one. "* I don't know if you wrote this with C# in mind, but in C, for instance, function pointers do have a type.

Comment: @MehdiCharife: the question is tagged C#.

Comment: @MehdiCharife: The question is not whether a function pointer *has* a type. The question is whether a function pointer in C++ is *self describing*.  How in C++ would you take a variable of type `void*` that contains a function pointer and determine from it alone what the type of the function is?  Pointers are not guaranteed to be self describing in C++ to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is because, when you hold a delegate to a member method, the OO framework "knows" you are holding a reference to the holding object, whereas with function pointers, first of all function isn't necessarily a member method and second of all, if the function is a member methods, the OO framework doesn't know it has to prevent the owning object from being freed.

Answer (score 2):

Function pointers are just memory addresses.

Delegates are objects that have methods and properties:
-BeginInvoke
-DynamicInvoke
-Invoke
-Method
-Target
etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain with C++ examples because it's a language where this problem is present (and solved another way).

A mere function pointer just holds the address of a function, nothing else.

Consider the function

```
void f(int x) { return; }
```

Now, a simple function pointer is declared and assigned like this:

```
void (*fptr)(int) = &f;
```

And you can use it simply:

```
foo(5); // calls f(5)
```

However, in an object oriented language we usually deal with member functions, not free functions. And this is where things get nasty. Consider the following class:

```
class C { void g(int x) { return; } };
```

Declaring a function pointer to C::g is done like this:

```
void (*C::gptr)(int) = &C::g;
```

The reason why we need a different syntax is that member functions have a hidden `this` parameter, thus their signature is different.

For the same reason, calling them is problematic. That `this` parameter needs a value, which means you need to have an instance. Calling a pointer to a member function is done like this:

```
C c;
(c.*gptr)(5);  // calls c.g(5);
```

Aside from the weird syntax, the real problem with this is that you need to pass the object together with your function pointer when you really just want to pass around one thing.

The obvious idea is to encapsulate the two, and that's what a delegate is. This is why a delegate is considered more OOP. I have no idea why it is considered more type-safe (maybe because you can cast function pointers to void*).

BTW the C++ solution in C++0x is adopted from Boost. It is called `std::function` and `std::bind` and works like this:

```
std::function<void (C*, int)> d = std::bind(&c::g, &c);
d(5); // calls c.g(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function pointer can have no knowledge of the instance it belongs to unless you pass it in explicitly - all function pointers are to static members. A delegate, on the other hand, can be a regular member of the class, and the correct instance of the object will be used when the delegate is invoked.

Comment: *"A function pointer can have no knowledge of the instance it belongs to unless you pass it in explicitly"* Isn't this how OO works under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose one wants to design a general purpose `anyprintf` method which can behave as either `fprintf`, `sprintf`, `cprintf` [console printf with color support].  One approach would be to have it accept a function that accepts a `void*` and a `char` along with a `void*` and a va_list; it should then for each character of output call the passed-in function, passing it the supplied pointer and the character to be output.

Given such a function, one could implement `vsprintf` and `fprintf` [ignoring their return values for simplicitly] via:

```
void fprint_function(void* data, char ch) { fputc( (FILE*)data, ch); }
void sprint_function(void* data, char ch) { char**p = (char**)data; *((*p)++) = ch; }
void fprint_function(void* data, char ch) { cputchar( ch); }
void vfprintf(FILE *f, va_list vp, const char *fmt, va_list vp)
{
  vsanyprintf(fprint_function, (void*)f, st, vp);
}
void vsprintf(char *st, va_list vp, const char *fmt, va_list vp)
{
  vsanyprintf(fprint_function, (void*)f, st, vp);
}
void vcprintf(va_list vp, const char *fmt, va_list vp)
{
  vsanyprintf(cprint_function, (void*)0, st, vp);
}
```

Effectively, the combination of the function pointer and `void*` behave as a method.  Unfortunately, there's no way for the compiler to ensure that the data which is passed in the `void*` will be of the form expected by the supplied function.  C++ and other object-oriented language add in compile-time validation of such type consistency.